# GitLab responseStatus=400 Bad Request FATAL: invalid argument ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, dotenv

I am trying to use GitLab artifact dotenv file

In my GitLab CI YAML file, I wrote this block of code:

```yaml
stages:
  - build

build:
  image: maven:3.9.5-sapmachine-21
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean install spring-boot:run
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
```

In the build log, I am seeing this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  39.144 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-25T12:07:22Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Uploading artifacts for successful job
Uploading artifacts...
build.env: found 1 matching files and directories  
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "dotenv" to coordinator... POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/7/artifacts: 400 Bad Request (Invalid Format)  id=7 responseStatus=400 Bad Request status=400 token=64_BFV8L
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "dotenv" to coordinator... POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/7/artifacts: 400 Bad Request (Invalid Format)  id=7 responseStatus=400 Bad Request status=400 token=64_BFV8L
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "dotenv" to coordinator... POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/7/artifacts: 400 Bad Request (Invalid Format)  id=7 responseStatus=400 Bad Request status=400 token=64_BFV8L
FATAL: invalid argument                            
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

How to use dotenv file?

Comment: What are the contents of your `build.env` file? Do they conform to the rules/limitations stated in the [dotenv report documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of your `build.env` file are not in the correct format. You need to ensure that the file is a properly formatted dotenv file that also adheres to the additional restrictions as specified in [the dotenv report documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv). The documentation also contains examples of how to correctly use this feature.

If you need to use a dotenv file that's not conforming to this specification, you can always pass the file down to other jobs as a normal artifact file:

```yaml
# ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build.env
```

Then jobs should receive this artifact and you can consume them using whatever tooling for dotenv files you want.

Comment: This is correct, many thanks